# having trouble getting rid of unwanted vertices

Tags: mesh

reworked my model and now can not get rid of stray vertices ,how do I get rid of unwanted Vertices on a model?

Answer (score 2):

If they're close to useful vertices you can try remove doubles, if not you can select an useful vertex, then press Ctrl L (select linked) then press H to hide them; if the mesh has more useful parts go on and hide all useful vertices, then A to select all (unuseful) and X to delete.